# Can not change background color

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Card` component I try to change background color on when clicking on it, and change the `flipped` prop from `false` to `true`, but it is not working. What am I missing?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-violet-vbwp0?file=/src/App.js)

```js
function Card(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <FlipDiv
      style={{
        width: props.width,
        height: props.height
      }}
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}
    >
      <FlipperDiv>
        <img
          style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}
          src={props.flipped ? props.front : props.back}
          alt={props.id}
        />
      </FlipperDiv>
    </FlipDiv>
  );
}

const FlipperDiv = styled.div`
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;

  > img {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
`;

const FlipDiv = styled.div`
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: ${(props) => (props.flipped ? "yellowgreen" : "black")};
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function App() {
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setFlipped(true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Card
        id={1}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        back={`/img/back.png`}
        front={`/img/1.png`}
        flipped={flipped}
        handleClick={() => handleClick(1)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `flipped` prop of your `Card` component to your `FlipDiv` component so that you can use it in the styles.

```js
<FlipDiv
  style={{
    width: props.width,
    height: props.height
  }}
  onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}
  flipped={props.flipped}
>
```